# Using CLion & PyCharm with GitKraken

Tags: pycharm, clion, jetbrains-ide, gitkraken

Has anyone used JetBrains product ( CLion, PyCharm, etc... ) that supports Git with GitKraken? I want to use CLion & PyCharm for code editing and testing and use GitKraken for git stuff, but I am worried that changing git may cause some problem in PyCharm & CLion.

The answer from JetBrains dev was:

> That depends on how GitKraken works (sorry, never tried it). Technically, PyCharm/CLion's VCS support is a wrapper around the native command-line client (git, hg, e.t.c), so if GitKraken also uses the same native client and follows the standard protocol for the respective VCS, there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: What I describe below is more like an educated guess than a secured and confirmed answer, but might help to give some insight.

GitKraken does not use the native command line, but interacts with repositories via nodeGit. As stated [in the axosoft blog](https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-git-gui-client-mac-windows-linux/):

> It works directly with your repositories with no dependencies—you
> don’t even need to have Git installed on your system. GitKraken is
> built with NodeGit, a Git framework that is primarily developed and
> maintained by members of the GitKraken development team

It also

> follows the standard protocol for the respective VCS

and works in parallel with other git clients (for example git bash, VisualStudio and JetBrains Rider git plugins) without problems, so I would expect it to work properly with the frameworks you mentioned.